# How to stop script from running when the device is a mobile handset?

Tags: javascript, mobile

I had a look at at some previous posts but they seem to be for touch screens. I need this script to be bypassed when the device is a mobile phone. Tablets work fine. I not sure where or what code should be inserted.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var _glc =_glc || []; _glc.push('all_ag9zfmNsaWNrZGVza2NoYXRyDgsSBXVzZXJzGO7GtxoM');
var glcpath = (('https:' == document.location.protocol) ?     'https://my.clickdesk.com/clickdesk-ui/browser/' : 
'http://my.clickdesk.com/clickdesk-ui/browser/');
var glcp = (('https:' == document.location.protocol) ? 'https://' : 'http://');
var glcspt = document.createElement('script'); glcspt.type = 'text/javascript'; 
glcspt.async = true; glcspt.src = glcpath + 'livechat-new.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(glcspt,  s);
</script>
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341956/load-jquery-mobile-script-only-for-mobile-devices

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser