# How: jquery -> jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a web site built with jquery which is not ready for mobile devices.  First no touch and second, I think using jquery the dimensions are not quite what I expect.  Stuff doesn't quite fit where it belongs.  I'm assuming I need to go to jquery-mobile, but how.

Do I add the jquery-mobile scripts, before or after?  Do I replace jquery?  Can I keep my current html or do I need to add class tags.  I don't want to throw anything away.  I just want to change lines where I am getting dimension values to use jquery-mobile, and add touch, and ...

Here's my headers. 
Can someone say how I should change them to incorporate jquery-mobile?  Thanks.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't include all the files everytime.

What you should do is detect what device the user is using (computer or mobile device) and load the appropriates files.

Check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11343209/3974585) for more informations.

Note that the correct way of linkink script with Jquery Mobile is :

1. jquery-mobile.css
2. jquery.js
3. jquery-mobile.js